# Ember: click event on a view not firing

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a list of `race-item`s, each rendered as a view:

```
        <ul>
            {{#each race in controller}}
                {{render "race-item" race class="race-item"}}
                {{else}}
                <li id="imagine">{{#link-to 'races.create'}}Imagine Faster{{/link-to}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
```

In the view class, I want use a click event to toggle a property:

```
App.RaceItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    templateName: 'raceItem',
    classNameBindings: ['isSelected:selected'],
    isSelected: false,
    click: function(e) {
        this.set('isSelected', true);
    }
});
```

This click event will not fire, it seems, unless it is a DOM element that normally handles clicks (`a`, `button`, etc.).

How can I get a click to fire on my `li`? I wrap everything in an anchor because there are child elements with their own events and actions.

Followup question: It seems like even if I get my click working, it will only set the current view's `isSelected` property to true, but not toggle the rest of the views properties to false. Tips on accomplishing that?

Thanks. I'm dyin' here.

Comment: Click events should work on <li> and other elements that are not normally clickable.  Are you able to reproduce a basic fiddle to demonstrate this?  You can use this fiddle as a base: http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/790/

Comment: To toggle the rest of view properties to false you can send an action from your view to the arrayController `this.get('controller').send('selected')` where you would set the selected item in the parent arrayController. Observe that property for changes and set all the other items to `false`.  I can do an example if you have a fiddle to work from for the other problem or it might be best to ask it as a separate question so people can answer one or the other.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the issue in a bin. I'm pretty new to Ember and because the data setup is different (I'm using the local storage adapter), I can't get anything to render. At any rate, the click event on my <li> is definitely not firing (won't even log anything to the console). Could it have something to do with my use of `render`? I've tried stripping the template down to remove all other actions and events, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click events should work for all elements, including li. There are a number of ways to achieve what you are looking for: one is to send an event to the controller:

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({

  tagName: 'li',
  templateName: 'item-view',
  classNameBindings: ['isSelected:selected'],
  isSelected: false,
  click: function(e) {
    this.set('isSelected',true);
    this.get('controller').send('itemSelected', this);
  }

});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsbin.com/tolod/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks! Your jsbin example worked perfectly. I changed the {{render}} helper to a {{view}} helper and used the parent controller to handle the `itemSelected` action. Not sure why {{render}} didn't work.

Comment: Here is a working version with {{render}}. The render creates a controller for the itemview behind the scenes and therefore has the added benefit of allowing you to pass the choice as a model. Take a look at the console when you click an option. http://jsbin.com/diwew/3/edit

Comment: Good example, thanks, but click events on the view still aren't working when I use {{render}}. I'm certain your example is spot-on, but there must be something different about my code that I'm not aware of and can't communicate.

Comment: But the example I provided using {{render}} works? It definitely something in your environment; possibly the version of Ember? Best way  to get help would be to reproduce the issue in a JSBin. You may be loading only the template and not the view with your render statement.